# Relative scoring system without much effect from outliers

Tags: algorithms, agreement-statistics, rating

I am trying to assign scores to phone's specifications to calculate a final rating score for each phone. However, when I was scoring based on megapixels. I found that one of the phones 'A' has a 41MP camera. But all other phones have 8MP or less, which is pretty good for a phone. Right now, when I grade relatively wrt phone A (rating 5/5), all other phones get a score of 1 or 2 out of 5. However I would like it to be a little more fair, as it was just one phone with a very high value. Could you suggest me the best way to go about solving this issue where the relative grading is more fair?

Comment: why not rank the phones, and score accordingly? So in this case, the phone with the 41mp camera would get the top score, and others would be ranked down through the bottom score.

Comment: I would want to rate all the other phones low, but maybe 3.5 or 4 out of 5. Giving them a score of 1 or 2 makes it seem like their camera's are useless, which is not really the case.

Comment: take the logs of the megapixels? This would reduce the 41mp camera the most, while reducing the others ones less.

Comment: Side note -- Nokia 808 is actually doing 5mpix photos, the huge sensor is to emulate lens zoom only.